# Controller method being called 2 on Search button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

Here is my set up. I have Telerik Grid. Here is what the .cshtml.

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<UserViewModel>().Name("UserGrid")
        .DataBinding(binding => binding.Ajax().Select("List", "Account", Model.ToRoute(Html))
                                              .Insert("Insert", "Account")
                                              .Delete("Delete", "Account")
                                              .Update("Save", "Account"))
        .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(model => model.UserName))
        .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Template(@<text>
                @Html.Partial("GridSearchTool")
            </text>))
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(u => u.Email)
                   .EditorTemplateName("EmailAddress")
                   .Filterable(true)
                   .Sortable(true)
                   .Width(300);
        })
        .Pageable()
        .Filterable()
        .Reorderable(reordering => reordering.Columns(true))
        .Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Height(500).Enabled(false))
        .Editable(editing => editing.Enabled(true)
                                    .DisplayDeleteConfirmation(true)
                                    .Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
                                    .TemplateName("UserEditor"))
        .ClientEvents(events => events.OnEdit("onRowEdit")
                                      .OnError("onGridError")
                                      .OnLoad("gridLoaded")
                                      .OnDataBinding("gridAjaxBinding")
                                      .OnDataBound("gridAjaxBound")
                                      .OnSave("gridAjaxSaved"))
```

Here is an entry in my Global.ascx for Routes.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                "Users", // Route Name
                "Account/{action}/{username}", // URL with parameters              
                new { controller = "Account", action = "Search", username = "" }
            );
```

You will see I have places the Seach as a partial view attached in my grid toolbar. It randers as one Text Box, Buttons (Search and Clear).

Here is the screen shot.

[image: Image of my page]

When I load the grid in my controller here is the functions/actions it calls.
1) Action Index
2) Action List

Here are the exaple.

```
public ActionResult Index(string username)
        {
            return View(new GridViewModel
            {                
                Query = username,
                QueryField = "Email",
                GridName = "UserGrid",
                Controller = "Account"
            });
        }

  [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
        [GridAction]
        public ActionResult List(string username)        
        {
            return Json(GetGridModel(DatabaseContext.FromContext()));
        }
```

This work fine when I initially load the grid. Now I have lots of data on my page and i want to find a particular record so i type my query or string in the text box in the search text box. When i do that here are the controller methods being called.

1) Index (with query entered in the search box)
2) List (with query entered in the search box)
3) List (with query entered in the search box)

I dont know why it called the List method mutliple times. 
I also tried to change the Global.ascx routes with calling different method instead of index but that does not work. It still called the Index multiple times.

I would appreciate any help or ideas regarding this issue.

Also here are the some Javascript methods .

Thanks for the quick reply. Here are both methods i found on one of the java script.

```
gridAjaxBinding = function (evt) {
        var grid = $(evt.target);
        if (grid.length) {
            grid.block({
                message: '<div class="loading"><img src="/Content/images/busy.gif"><span>Loading...</span></div>'
            });
        }
    };
gridAjaxBound = function (evt) {
        var grid = $(evt.target);
        if (grid.length) {
            grid.unblock();
        }

        grid.unbind('edit', gridAjaxEditing);
        grid.bind('edit', gridAjaxEditing);

        var gridId = '#' + grid.attr('id');

        // Get the export link as jQuery object
        var $exportLink = $('#export');
        if ($exportLink.length) {
            grid = grid.data('tGrid');
            // Get its 'href' attribute - the URL where it would navigate to
            var href = $exportLink.attr('href');

            // Update the 'page' parameter with the grid's current page
            href = href.replace(/page=([^&]*)/, 'page=' + grid.currentPage);

            // Update the 'orderBy' parameter with the grids' current sort state
            href = href.replace(/orderBy=([^&]*)/, 'orderBy=' + (grid.orderBy || '~'));

            // Update the 'filter' parameter with the grids' current filtering state
            href = href.replace(/filter=(.*)/, 'filter=' + (grid.filterBy || '~'));

            // Update the 'href' attribute
            $exportLink.attr('href', href);
        }

        setupContextMenu(grid);
    };
```

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the javascript code you did not post. This behavior occurs if you call the `grid.filter(...)` method in `gridAjaxBinding` or `gridAjaxBound`. I faced the same issue and it was related to setting `grid.filter` twice. The follwing code is working for us (oversimplified):

```
$("#button").on("click", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  evo.filterGridData();
});

evo.filterGridData = function filterGridData() {
  var searchTerm = $("#searchTerm").val().replace(/'/g,"''");
  var grid = $("#grid").data("tGrid");
  grid.filter("substringof(FieldToSearchFor,'" + searchTerm + "')");
};
```

Comment: Hi I have added those 2 methods to my question as well. Can you please review them and let me know if anything is wrong with them? I will also try to debug these methods.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is nothing suspicious in your code. What happens if you leave `gridAjaxBound` empty. Maybe there is sth. in `setupContextMenu` or the search button triggers a double rebind.

Comment: I found 1 more thing. In my GridSearchTool View, I have this below code 
dojo.addOnLoad(function () {
            applyGridFilter('#@Model.GridName', '@Model.QueryField', '@Html.Raw(Model.Query)', 'substringof');
        }); 
This code is calling the function applyGridFilter and there It is calling tGrid.filter function. Here is code of the function.
I can copy that function if you want to review?

Comment: Would be nice if you post the code, imho there is a simple double ajax request somewhere in your javascript. I'll update my post with a simplified version we use.